# Android spinner to change setContentView

Tags: java, android

So, I have a spinner with two different options thus far. What I am trying to accomplish is, if "First Spinner Option" is chosen, then I setContentView to a specific layout and execute code corresponding to that layout. The same goes if "Second Spinner Option" is chosen. I know that I need to use setOnItemSelectedListener to a certain extent, but I am not sure how this would work exactly. Below is a quick mock up of what I'm trying to do in coding terms

```
spinner.setonItemSelectedListener(this);
    if(spinner = first spinner option){
         setContentView(R.layout.lay1);
         //other code here
    }elseif(spinner = second spinner option){
         setContentView(R.layout.lay2);
         //other code here
    }
```

I know the syntax is bad here, Im just trying to get a general idea of how this could be done.

EDIT: @CodeMagic
This is how my code is setup thus far. 'items' is just an array of strings with 2 elements.

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.my_spinner_style, items) {

            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
                Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Exo-Bold.otf");
                ((TextView) v).setTypeface(tf);
                return v;
            }


            public View getDropDownView(int position,  View convertView,  ViewGroup parent) {
                View v =super.getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent);
                Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Exo-Bold.otf");
                ((TextView) v).setTypeface(tf);
                //v.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);

                return v;
            }
    };


    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);                                 
    gasChoice.setAdapter(adapter);  

    addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection();
}

public void addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection(){
    gasChoice = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.gasChoice);
    gasChoice.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelected());

}
```

Comment: I would avoid this logic pattern but instead have one layout with an empty area where the selection in your spinner would inflate a new layout in, or use fragments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know exactly what the problem is you are having but its pretty close. You just need to add the method

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
     TextView tv = (TextView)arg1;  // get the TextView selected
     String text = tv.getText().toString();
     if(text.equals("FirstText")){   // compare the text in the box
          setContentView(R.layout.lay1);
     //other code here
     }elseif(text.equals("FirstText")){
          setContentView(R.layout.lay2);
         //other code here
     }
}
```

There are different ways of doing this such as getting the position (`arg2`) and comparing that to what's in your adapter but since I don't know how you are doing any of that, this is the easiest way to get you started.

Comment: I've updated my post to contain some more information that might help. Obviously I need to create my onItemSelected method. But this is what Ive got thus far.

Comment: I don't know exactly where the problem is you are having. Create the method and use the `position` to compare it to what's at that position in the `Adapter`